# DriverManager tries to use mariadb driver when connecting to h2 database

Tags: h2, mariadb

I'm doing some testing and got the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid connection URL url  dbc:h2:db/test
at org.mariadb.jdbc.JDBCUrl.parse(JDBCUrl.java:144)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:95)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
```

The code I'm using:

```
Class.forName("org.h2.Driver"); //load h2 driver
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:h2:db/test";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, "sa", "");
```

I also test something related to mariadb/mysql, so the mariadb driver is also on classpath in addition to the h2 driver (eclipse project). If I remove the mariadb driver from classpath the connection works.

To my knowledge it should be possible to have multiple jdbc drivers on classpath or have I understood something wrong?

(h2 is version 1.3.176 and mariadb-java-client is 1.2.0)

EDIT: Using mariadb-java-client 1.2.2 removes the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that this was a bug in the mariadb-jdbc-driver

https://mariadb.atlassian.net/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/CONJ-167

Answer (score 0):

I would assume this was some kind of bug, since I have not seen the problem after updating to mariadb-java-client 1.2.2 .